# Convert Date to number (not timestamp) in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am looking for a way to convert a javascript Date to a number that represents the amount of days passed since , for example, 1.1.1900, for that date. As it is usually done with timestamps and miliseconds.

Can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried looking at the documentation for [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), that might give you some ideas.

Comment: With time and effort - yes.

Comment: You are likely getting down-voted because this question shows an obvious lack of effort and research. This is very basic date manipulation found on just about every tutorial out there.

Comment: I know that I can reimplement that based on timestamps but I am pretty sure there already is an implementation for exactly that and I could not find anything by using google. Maybe I simply used the wrong terms for it.

Comment: I'm sure you can probably search for date/time libraries that already implement that for you, but no, there isn't a native function. But it's trivial to implement.

Comment: @Ferenjito: What is wrong with using the timestamp? What problem do you have with subtracting two numbers and then scaling it from milliseconds to days? It's trivial math.

Comment: OK, you are right, its trivial but it seems so basic that I thought there has to bee a native implementation for it. Seems that I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the javascript function getTime().

Code:

```
var a = new Date();
alert(a.getTime());
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u34feh9r/)

According to getTime() definition:

> The getTime() method returns the numeric value corresponding to the
>   time for the specified date according to universal time.

More can be found in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

UPDATE:

If you want to have it in no of days then you would need to calculate it or use library like moment.js

[Working Fiddle for Days](http://jsfiddle.net/u34feh9r/1/)

Comment: rather looks like timestamp, which is what I did not want.

Comment: the value returned by the getTime() method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC, so i guess that is what u wanted right? @Ferenjito, thisi i guess u can convert to no of days after that

Comment: No, I wanted days, not miliseconds, but I see I have to calculate this (which is trivial of course).

Comment: yeah unfortunately u would have to calculate or use a library like moment.js

Comment: @Ferenjito: added fiddle that actually convert the miliseconds to days. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

For example something like:

```js
    var date1 = new Date("1/Jan/1900 00:00:00");
    var date2 = new Date("20/Nov/2012 19:15:00");

    var diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();

    var days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    diff -=  days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    var hours = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    diff -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);

    var mins = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60));
    diff -= mins * (1000 * 60);

    var seconds = Math.floor(diff / (1000));
    diff -= seconds * (1000);

    document.write(days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + mins + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds");
```